# set picture in apple watchface programmatically

Tags: watchkit, watchos-2

WatchOS 2 does not allow custom watch faces, but users may create a somewhat custom face by selecting a background picture. Is there a way to set that picture programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible, there is no API with access to Watch Faces.

Comment: I'm guessing there's no control over the picture set? I can save an image to a file, it's odd that there's no way to manipulate the imagesetters count toward the album the watchface uses. Maybe watchOS 3...

Comment: it's not odd, this is the same as not being able to access heart rate in watchOS 1, etc. - Apple usually 'shields' users from using all of the possible API for the sake of UX (or so they say), I doubt it they will allow this, as much as they won't let you change anything in Dashboard on the iPhone from 3rd party apps.